# groupdel: cannot remove the primary group of user 'administrator'

Tags: users, user-management, groups

When I try to delete the group `pro1` (`groupdel pro1`) it shows the error:

> groupdel: cannot remove the primary group of user 'administrator'

And when I create new user from AD server, the user's default group is `pro1`.

How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: change administrator's primary group to some other existing group

Comment: I tried to change administrator's primary group,but it can not work.
$usermod -g test administrator
$usermod: user 'administrator' does not exist in /etc/passwd
$usermod: failed to unlock /etc/shadow
'administrator' even not exist in /etc/passwd.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is documented in the man page. From `man groupdel`:

> You may not remove the primary group of any existing user. You must
>   remove the user before you remove the group.

So you need to make the primary group of user `administrator` something other than `pro1` and then you should be able to remove group `pro1`.

**Example:**

```
$ sudo groupdel foobar 
groupdel: cannot remove the primary group of user 'foobar'
$ sudo usermod -g foo foobar  ## Change the primary group of user "foobar" from "foobar" to "foo"
$ sudo groupdel foobar  ## Done
```

Comment: userdel: cannot remove entry 'administrator' from /etc/passwd

Comment: @roadkiller180 Whats the output of `getent passwd administrator` ?

Comment: administrator:*:10002:10007:Administrator:/home/administrator:/bin/bash

Comment: chenmark:*:10000:10007:Mark Chen:/home/chenmark:/bin/bash
wulucy:*:10001:10007:Lucy wu:/home/wulucy:/bin/bash
cathysong:*:10007:10007:cathy song:/home/cathysong:/bin/bash
zhumike:*:50000:10007:mike zhu:/home/zhumike:/bin/bash
pro1:*:50001:10007:pro1:/home/pro1:/bin/bash
test:*:50002:10007:test:/home/test:/bin/bash
It's very strange, Every new user's GID is 10007,Do you why?

Comment: @roadkiller180 yeah, there could be configurations leading to this..why are the UIDs>10000 ? Also whats the output of `grep 'administrator' /etc/passwd` ?

Comment: grep 'administrator' /etc/passwd
output: postgres:*:111:120:PostgreSQLadministrator,,,:/var/lib/postgresql:/bin/bash

Comment: I set UID range in smb.conf from 10000-20000 at the first time,and now change to 50000-60000,so you can see some UID like 50002,50001 as i mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: @roadkiller180 This behavior that you can't remove users that are not in `/etc/passwd` is a known bug.. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/accountsservice/+bug/988072 ..as you are using samba you are affected by this..also if you have any conf related issues with samba like the GID issue you have mentioned, you should ask that as a new question..